# Nullpointerexception at onStop() method

Tags: java, android, timer, nullpointerexception

I used this sample code in a similar clock application:
http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-apps-to-show-digital-time-in_19.html

It works fine, however when using the back or home buttons I get a nullpointerexception in the log. It says unable to stop application.
If I remove the methods :

`timer.cancel();

timer.purge();

timer = null;`

It works OK, but I suppose this would be memory consuming?
/M

> 08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {se.macke.binarycounter/se.macke.binarycounter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2624)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2690)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:964)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at se.macke.binarycounter.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:209)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1170)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:3873)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2619)
>   08-19 19:00:13.438: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     ... 11 more
>   08-19 19:00:16.398: I/Process(1064): Sending signal. PID: 1064 SIG: 9
>   08-19 19:00:16.450: I/ActivityManager(61): Process se.macke.binarycounter (pid 1064) has died.
>   08-19 19:00:16.450: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '4079da00 se.macke.binarycounter/se.macke.binarycounter.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
>   08-19 19:00:16.450: E/InputDispatcher(61): channel '4079da00 se.macke.binarycounter/se.macke.binarycounter.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: If you get a nullpointer exception, how about you post it here so we know what it's about.

Comment: what happens if you take away `timer=null` this is the 1st thing that jumps out as causing a NPE

Comment: If you `null` something in `onStop` make sure that it is (re)created in `onStart` - symmetry is your friend.

Comment: Where are you putting that timer code?  And what's the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: If I remove all of the methods I posted above it works fine, if I take just one or two away, i still get the nullpointerexception. The timer is created and recreated the same way as in the sample code, the only things I changed are how the clock is displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [visible lifetime](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) of an `Activity` is between `onStart()` and `onStop()`. By setting your timer to `null` and then using the back button or the home button and accessing the application again doesn't ensure that the `Activity` had terminated, it simply wasn't visible anymore. So you end up accessing something that is pointing to `null` and hence the `NPE`.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, however the NPE doesn't appear after accessing the app again, it appears when exiting via the home or back button.